# @Preview not working - Jetpack Compose 1.0.0-alpha02

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I have been using the preview just fine in the dev-015 release, but when I updated to alpha-01 and alpha-02 it stopped working, I have restarted , cleaned cache, rebuild and the problem just persists

here is my code

```
val recipeList = listOf(Recipe(R.drawable.header,"Test", listOf("Azucar","Tomate","lasagna")),
        Recipe(R.drawable.header,"Test", listOf("Azucar","Tomate","lasagna")),
        Recipe(R.drawable.header,"Test", listOf("Azucar","Tomate","lasagna")))


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            RecipeList(recipeList)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RecipeCard(recipe: Recipe) {
    val image = imageResource(R.drawable.header)
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
        val imageModifier = Modifier
                .preferredHeight(150.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))

        Image(image,modifier= imageModifier, contentScale = ContentScale.Crop)
        Spacer(Modifier.preferredHeight(16.dp))
        Text(recipe.title, style = typography.h6)
        for(ingredient in recipe.ingredients){
            Text(ingredient,style = typography.body2)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RecipeList(recipeList:List<Recipe>){
    LazyColumnFor(recipeList) { item ->
        RecipeCard(recipe = item)
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun RecipePreview(){
    RecipeCard(recipeList[0])
}

data class Recipe(
        @DrawableRes val imageResource: Int,
        val title: String,
        val ingredients: List<String>
)
```

Here are my dependencies

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jetexample"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion kotlin_version
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'

    //Fundamental building blocks of Compose's programming model and state management, and core runtime for the Compose Compiler Plugin to target.
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$compose_version"

    //Fundamental components of compose UI needed to interact with the device, including layout, drawing, and input.
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"

    //Build Jetpack Compose UIs with ready to use Material Design Components. This is the higher level entry point of Compose, designed to provide components that match those described at www.material.io.
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"

    //Write Jetpack Compose applications with ready to use building blocks and extend foundation to build your own design system pieces.
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:$compose_version"

    //Build animations in their Jetpack Compose applications to enrich the user experience.
    implementation "androidx.compose.animation:animation:$compose_version"

    //In charge of annotators like @Preview and tooling for render views
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

and my project gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jetexample"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion kotlin_version
    }
}

    dependencies {
    
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
    
        //Fundamental building blocks of Compose's programming model and state management, and core runtime for the Compose Compiler Plugin to target.
        implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$compose_version"
    
        //Fundamental components of compose UI needed to interact with the device, including layout, drawing, and input.
        implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    
        //Build Jetpack Compose UIs with ready to use Material Design Components. This is the higher level entry point of Compose, designed to provide components that match those described at www.material.io.
        implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
        implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
    
        //Write Jetpack Compose applications with ready to use building blocks and extend foundation to build your own design system pieces.
        implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$compose_version"
        implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:$compose_version"
    
        //Build animations in their Jetpack Compose applications to enrich the user experience.
        implementation "androidx.compose.animation:animation:$compose_version"
    
        //In charge of annotators like @Preview and tooling for render views
        implementation "androidx.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    }
    
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            // Treat all Kotlin warnings as errors
            allWarningsAsErrors = true
            freeCompilerArgs += '-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn'
            // Enable experimental coroutines APIs, including Flow
            freeCompilerArgs += '-Xopt-in=kotlin.Experimental'
            freeCompilerArgs += '-Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies'
    
            // Set JVM target to 1.8
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
```

My emulator just shows this

[image]

I have tried everything but it seems is not rendering the preview for me, I have been struggling with jetpack compose each time I update it but cant seem to get it work stable in each update of the API, does someone knows what is happening here ?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you try to run the app in the emulator or a real device? I'm getting the same issue as you every time I use the ContentScale parameter of Image - and when I run the app I get an error like "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: maxWidth(1080) must be >= minWidth(2022)"

Comment: from `1.0.0-alpha01`, `imageResource()` is only for loading image asset, if your `R.drawable.header` is vector asset, using `vectorResource()` instead of `imageResource()`